# Need suggestion with Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing an update query where I need to update some values in a column using REGEXP_REPLACE function.

I had written the below query which works correctly.

```
update my_table_name
set column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '"MyValue":0', '"MyValue":2' )
WHERE column_id=1234;
```

However, after - "MyValue": it can be any number ranging from 0-9. So I am trying to have a check such that it match the first string i.e. - "MyValue": and anything number after that and if that matches the next value will be whatever I will be replacing it with.

Basically I need to match the string - "MyValue:" and any digit that comes after that in the REGEX_REPLACE

Any suggestions. Should I be using REGEX_REPLACE or something else. OR  the regex needs some tweaking

Comment: Would the replacement _always_ be `"MyValue":2`?  By the way, does this column contain JSON content?

Comment: Are you just talking about having a `\d` digit marker instead of `0` in your regex pattern?

Comment: It seems like you are looking for `regexp_replace(column_name,"MyValue":[0-9]','"MyValue":2')`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes the replacement will always be "MyValue": 0 for anything that it matches for "MyValue":<any_number>

Comment: @markalex. Thank you, your suggestion worked. Actually i was adding a $ in the end which was not making it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `REGEXP_REPLACE` as follows:

```sql
UPDATE my_table_name
SET column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name, '"MyValue":[0-9]', '"MyValue":2')
WHERE column_id = 1234;
```